# CosmosDB - OR operator not working with JOIN

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I have two documents in my collection:

```
{
  "ViewAll": true,
  "GroupIDs": []
}
```

and:

```
{
  "ViewAll": false,
  "GroupIDs": ["super-admin"]
}
```

I would expect the following query to return both documents:

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM c 
JOIN groupIDs in c.GroupIDs
WHERE (c.ViewAll = true OR groupIDs IN("super-admin"))
```

However I'm only getting back the second document.

Playing around with queries I noticed that if I exclude a WHERE clause but keep the JOIN it is still limiting the result set to just the one that has GroupIDs

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM c 
JOIN groupIDs in c.GroupIDs
```

Is the JOIN limiting the result set because there are no entries in the GroupIDs array? Is there a way to get the results I want?

Comment: some databases handle "null" values in odd ways.  I'm not proficient in azure, but try replacing `groupIDs IN("super-admin")` with your database's equivalent of `(groupIDs is not null and groupIDs IN("super-admin"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the JOIN limiting the result set because there are no entries in
>   the GroupIDs array?

The answer is YES. So,maybe you could use [ARRAY_CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#BuiltinFunctions) instead of JOIN to implement your requirements.

```
SELECT VALUE c FROM c 
where c.ViewAll = true or ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.GroupIDs, "super-admin",true)
```

Output:

[image]

Also,you could refer to my previous case:[cosmos db query self join with null array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49994511/cosmos-db-query-self-join-with-null-array)

Comment: The answer you provided based on the information I gave you was spot-on and for that reason I'm giving you the credit. Although the reality is that my situation is a bit more complicated than that. I'm specifically using IN because there is a set of c.GroupIDs that I'm checking against, but I'm not checking against just one value "super-admin", rather it can be a list of values. Possibly "super-admin", "group-a" AND "group-b". If any c.GroupIDs matches any of those I want it to to be returned in the results. Any ideas?